# Match any class with a specific method signature?

Tags: scala

Atm I have a lot of:

```
t match {
    case And(lhs, rhs) => { attach(lhs, rhs) }
    case Or(lhs, rhs) => { attach(lhs, rhs) }
    ...
}
```

is it possible to somehow match any class with the signature `Class(lhs: ExprTree, rhs: ExprTree)`?

Comment: If they all go to `attach`, why do you need to pattern match at all?

Comment: Please give a full code example that compiles and runs. What is `t`? What are the full examples of `And` and `Or`?

Comment: If you're doing the same thing with every input of that shape, and you don't want to change your current types (or they aren't yours), type classes are a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to mark all classes like you've mentioned with special interface (trait).

```
object o {

  trait AsTuple {
    def a: ExprTree
    def b: ExprTree
  }
  trait ExprTree
  case object Leaf extends ExprTree
  case class And(a: ExprTree, b: ExprTree) extends ExprTree with AsTuple
  case class Or(a: ExprTree, b: ExprTree) extends ExprTree with AsTuple

  def p: ExprTree = ???

  p match {
    case d: AsTuple => // attach(d.a, d.b)
  }



}
```

Comment: More natural to me would be `class BinOp(a:ExprTree,b:ExprTree) extends ExprTree... case class And(...)  extends BinOp` since that's what's being modelled, not the implementation artifact that they take two parameters... Here we have a classic class hierarchy, and sometimes there's nothing wrong with that...

Comment: absolutely agree... but the initial question assume matching for "any class" but not only binary operations.

Comment: But your solution already requires altering the class definition (with `AsTuple`) which won't be possible for "any class". So if your'e (reasonably) assuming the class definitions can be changed, might as well model it properly. If you can't change them, then as @travisbrown says, typeclasses are the way to go...

Comment: I should have made it more clear in the op: `t` is not limited to binary classes, I'm writing a compiler so there are more cases (for example `case If(expr, thn, els) => { ... }`. What rumoku suggested gave the result I wanted to but maybe it's not the best way to do it? I'm not good enough with Scala to understand which solution is the best